# Help with MySQL Query?

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

I have two tables `rooms` and `users`. I want to get only `rooms.room_id`, `users.user_name` with `user_id = 1`. I can get the result of all users with following sql...

```
select rooms.room_id,
       rooms.user_id,
       users.user_name 
  from rooms 
LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.user_id = users.user_id
```

When I do like this to filter the result with user_id = 1 ... I got error.

```
select rooms.room_id,
       rooms.user_id,
       users.user_name 
  from rooms where rooms.user_id = 1 
LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.user_id = users.user_id
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the query as:

```
select rooms.room_id,
       rooms.user_id,
       users.user_name 
  from rooms 
LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE roows.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

ANSI-92 JOIN syntax (when you see LEFT JOIN ...) dictates that the `WHERE` clause comes after the JOIN(s):

```
   SELECT r.room_id,
          r.user_id,
          u.user_name 
     FROM ROOMS r 
LEFT JOIN users ON u.user_id = r.user_id
    WHERE r.user_id = 1
```

You were close.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select rooms.room_id,
       rooms.user_id,
       users.user_name 
from rooms
LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE rooms.user_id = 1
```

The syntax of a simple SQL SELECT query is:

```
SELECT [a list of fields]
FROM [a single table name maybe with an alias, or a join of tables]
WHERE [a filter, applied over some fields of the tables in the FROM clause]
```

You could read an introductory tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

Answer (score 1):

It helps to state what error you get.

I would guess that the problem is that the where clause needs to be after the joins

```
select rooms.room_id,
   rooms.user_id,
   users.user_name 
from rooms 
  LEFT JOIN users ON rooms.user_id = users.user_id
where rooms.user_id = 1
```